# What is the purpose of the user mention of type "@@username@drupal.stackexchange.com" in chat?

Tags: support

One of the moderators mentioned a user by the format `@@username@drupal.stackexchange.com` in [a chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8192478#8192478).
AFAIK, the mentions of the format `@username` are enough for the users to be notified. So, what is the purpose of this type of mention? Should I use it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's called a 'Super Ping', launched in 2011 to allow moderators to 'summon' (probably a poor choice of words!!) a user to a chat room anywhere in the site.

> Super-Ping to Reach Individual Users
>
> The regular @ chat alerts only notify someone if they’ve been in the chat room in the last day or so (see chat notifications help). But did you know moderators can use a special @@ notification to contact anyone on your site, even if they have never been in the chat room? Moderators can use the @@ super-ping that will always put a notification in the user’s inbox.
> The syntax is
>
> @@
> or:
>
> @@@site.stackexchange.com
> So, for example, typing:
>
> @@98786@meta.stackoverflow.com
> would generate an inbox notification to me, even if I’ve never been in that chat room.

The above comes from the [Community moderator blog](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1):

That is an attempted superping, which even works if the target user was not in the room recently or doesn't even have a chat account. If the superping had worked, it would have appeared like a regular ping to all users.

Regular users can't use the superping, and can only ping users that have been in the chat room recently.

Answer (score 1):

@@username@drupal.stackexchange.com is another way to notify a user of a message left in chat. The difference with @username is that it notifies also those users who have never been in the chat room where the message has been left, or those users who have never been in any chat room.

@@username@drupal.stackexchange.com, differently from @username can be used from moderators, and only in chat. It is not used in comments.

Answer (score 1):

As other have explained, this is a superping.  The methods by which moderators can contact users are outlined in the [Moderator Cheat Sheet](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119111/moderator-cheat-sheet).  In particular, there are guidelines for [Contacting Users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119111/moderator-cheat-sheet/119114#119114).

As this was something that could be handled in public, I chose to do so.  Superpings also show up in the global inbox, and I was hoping that this user was still around on an SE site and would see it.

Comment: I know you wanted an answer to the question on Drupal 8. And I thought it is a very cool feature. My only concern was whether normal users could use it.